# Tense question - Hypothetical scenario in future

Tags: modal-verbs, future, sequence-of-tenses

> Finally, I believe that high school teenagers might resent the idea of being forced to do this type of work, and this resentment COULD result in not wanting to volunteer in social activities AFTER they **FINISH/FINISHED** school.

The situation is a hypothetical one in the future.
Considering that , should the tense of verb "finish" be simple past?

Like "If I HAD money , I could buy a car" or "Schools could ensure that students TOOK part."

Comment: *After they finish* is not in the future just because other parts of the sentence may be. Finish applies to any time after that. Finished sounds more like right then.